# Rails start what does web.1 mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When you do rails start it shows up with web.1. I know you can have multiple workers named differently but what does it mean?

Comment: Need more context.  How are you starting it, where does "web.1" show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! Gotcha
You must be using the Foreman

Quote from it's [Guide](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html)

> For the Procfile used at the top of this post, web.1 would be assigned
>   port 5000, worker.1 would be 5100, and clock.1 would be 5200. If you
>   were ran 2 web processes, web.2 would be assigned 5001.

So instead of `web` it shows `web.1`. Here digits are used to distinguish loggers which is usufull when more then one processes of web are used. Hope this clears your confusion :D.